# How to return JSON objects from spring boot controller methods?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, spring-boot, react-router

I am using spring boot along with react js and postgresql. I am trying to print the rows of table from postgresql to a react js page. I have used crud repository function findAll() in the controller method to get the List. My problem is that when I am printing the List in spring boot console, it prints the list but it's printing empty objects' list when that url is accessed.

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("User[id=%d, name='%s', email='%s']",this.id,this.name,this.email);
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{


}
```

WebController.java

```
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("home")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("whaaat");
        return "hi ssup";
    }

    @GetMapping("/save")
    public String process() {

        repository.save(new User("vidhi","vd@gmail.com"));
        System.out.print("apple ");
        return "Done";
    }

    @GetMapping("findall")
    @ResponseBody
    public Collection<User> findAll() {
        System.out.println("cc");
        List<User> users = (List<User>) repository.findAll();
        System.out.println(users);
        return users;
    }
}
```

On printing users in boot: [User[id=33, name='i', email='vd@gmail.com'], User[id=34, name='v', email='d@gmail.com']

on localhost:8080/findall: [{},{}]

What's going on wrong here? I am very confused and trying to figure this out since a lot of time and it's eating my head.

Any help would be wonderful!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does user have getters and setters?

Comment: org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#findAll method gives you Iterable<T>. How come you able to cast Iterable<T> to List<User> without running into java.lang.ClassCastException?

Comment: @SureshMSidy I didn't run into any exception.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli No, no getters and setters. Are they must?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli oh my god, thank you so much . Just by adding getters and setters , everything worked. I am such a noob but can you tell me the reason?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli oh my god, thank you so much . Just by adding getters and setters , everything worked. I am such a noob but can you tell me the reason?

Comment: Cool. I added this as the answer. I would appreciate if you accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have to add getters and setters to the User class.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
@GetMapping("findall", produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Collection<User>> findAll() {
    System.out.println("cc");
    List<User> users = (List<User>) repository.findAll();
    System.out.println(users);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(users);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks but this is also not working. It gives error APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE can't be resolved.

Comment: If it can't be resolved, you are missing critical dependencies. Check your pom. 

You need this and probably JPA

```<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>```

Answer (score 0):

change your repo to:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{


}
```